# How to manage the InApp Purchase Subscription restore use case?

Tags: android, ios, in-app-subscription

I have added in app purchase(subscription) in my iOS and android application.
I have also provided Restore functionality.
If restored successfully, I will call my server api and provide content to the user.

My question is that if any other user logged in my application and clicked on the Restore button in that case due to the same apple/gmail id it provides success and calls my server API.
How will we restrict any other user to take benefit from restore?

Answer (score 0):

You have the option to provide storage of the purchases logs at your backend, associating the user with the transactions. In that way you can keep track of who purchased what, implementing a validation process before giving the service to the user.

You may want to check this section

> Manage subscribers in your account database. Store the transaction_id,
> original_transaction_id, and product_id for each transaction, as a
> best practice to store transaction records for each customer. App
> Store generates a new value for transaction_id every time the
> subscription automatically renews or is restored on a new device.

From the documentation of [transaction_id](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstorereceipts/transaction_id)

Also the section for providing transactions validation is useful for this case. There you will see which receipt is sent back from Apple, how to access the transaction id, and how to take into account original transactions and renewals.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/storekit/in-app_purchase/validating_receipts_with_the_app_store